# Add a contact form to Module in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, contact-form, joomla-module

I'm using [this Joomla template](http://demo.omegatheme.com/joomla25/ot_zdesign/index.php/features/module-positions) with Joomla 2.5.x and i want to add a Contact Us form in to a **RIGHT** module in this template.

How can i add a Contact Us form to a module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a contact form extension that includes a module from the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms),  install, configure, then assign the module to the **right** position.

Comment: I need to create contact form with my own fields (text box, text area, drop down list, combo box, etc..). I have search for existing modules to do this. but i'm unable to find *non comercial* module for this. Are there any **Free** customizable contact form modules to do this ?